# Preventing "pass through" situations properly when using ECS based collision detection

Tags: entity-component-system, unity-dots, unity-job-system, burst

package versions I'm using:
Entities: com.unity.entities Version 0.51.1-preview.21
Documentation URL: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.51/manual/index.html

Physics: com.unity.physics Version 0.51.1-preview.21
Documentation URL: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.physics@0.51/manual/index.html

Havok Physics: com.havok.physics Version 0.51.1-preview.21
Documentation URL: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.havok.physics@0.50/manual/index.html

Hybrid Renderer: com.unity.rendering.hybrid Version 0.51.1-preview.21 - August 02, 2022
Documentation URL: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.rendering.hybrid@0.51/manual/index.html

I have implemented an ECS based collision detection system, and most of the time it correctly works. However, when I move game objects fast enough, the associated entities simply "pass through" each other instead of properly registering collisions. For demonstration, I will move the rightmost game object at normal speed towards the left. This is what should happen when collisions are detected properly:

[image]

Here is the sequence of method calls in my SystemBase script's OnUpdate:

```
protected override void OnUpdate()
    {
        spriteMeshModifiers = new List<SpriteMeshModifier>();
        List<GameObject> waterslimesDisplay = objectManagerController.displaySlimesGlobal;
        foreach (GameObject waterslimeDisplay in waterslimesDisplay) {
            spriteMeshModifiers.Add(waterslimeDisplay.GetComponent<SpriteMeshModifier>());
        }
        //consolidateGameObjectToPos2D(Vector3.zero, 0.1f);
        //revertGameObjectToInitialpos2D(0.1f);
        CallJobs();
        // Assign the positions of game objects entities are converted from to entity Translation values
        SyncEntityPositions();
        QueryVelocitiesAndUpdateStaticComponents();

        // Increase Solver Iteration to prevent "pass through" situations, but even then it sucks.
        Entities.WithBurst().ForEach((ref PhysicsStep physicsStep) =>
        {
            // Set the solver iteration count directly
            physicsStep.SolverIterationCount = 240;

        }).ScheduleParallel(Dependency).Complete();

        // Job Based Stateful Collision detection
        var collisionEventBufferType = GetBufferTypeHandle<StatefulCollisionEvent>();
        var entityType = GetEntityTypeHandle();
        var velocities = GetComponentDataFromEntity<Velocity>();
        var physicsVelocities = GetComponentDataFromEntity<PhysicsVelocity>();
        var isCollidedComponents = GetComponentDataFromEntity<IsCollidedComponent>();
        var isStatic = GetComponentDataFromEntity<IsStaticComponent>();
        var size = GetComponentDataFromEntity<SizeComponent>();
        var markForDelete = GetComponentDataFromEntity<MarkForDelete>();
        var ecb = World.GetOrCreateSystem<EndSimulationEntityCommandBufferSystem>().CreateCommandBuffer().AsParallelWriter();

        var collisionJob = new CollisionEventJob
        {
            CollisionEventBufferType = collisionEventBufferType,
            VelocityComponents = velocities,
            Velocities = physicsVelocities,
            IsCollidedComponent = isCollidedComponents,
            IsStatic = isStatic,
            Size = size,
            MarkForDelete = markForDelete,
            EntityType = entityType,
            Ecb = ecb
        };

        EntityQuery collisionQuery = GetEntityQuery(new EntityQueryDesc
        {
            All = new ComponentType[] { typeof(StatefulCollisionEvent), typeof(PhysicsVelocity) }
        });

        var collisionJobHandle = collisionJob.ScheduleParallel(collisionQuery, Dependency); //Schedule(collisionQuery, this.Dependency);
        World.GetOrCreateSystem<EndSimulationEntityCommandBufferSystem>().AddJobHandleForProducer(collisionJobHandle);

        // Chain the dependency so that it waits for both previous jobs and collisionJob to complete
        Dependency = JobHandle.CombineDependencies(Dependency, collisionJobHandle);

        // Wait for all jobs to complete before moving on to the next frame's Update
        Dependency.Complete();
       
        // Reset collided entity PhysicsVelocity and Velocity for collided entities
        ResetCollidedEntityVelocities();

        // Update the actual MonoBehavior game objects(e.g. size, disabling) based on conditions of the entities
        UpdateMonoBehaviorGameObjectsAfterCollision();
    }
```

And here is the job implementation:

```
[BurstCompile]
    public struct CollisionEventJob : IJobChunk
    {
        [NativeDisableParallelForRestriction] public ComponentDataFromEntity<IsStaticComponent> IsStatic;
        [NativeDisableParallelForRestriction] public ComponentDataFromEntity<SizeComponent> Size;
        [NativeDisableParallelForRestriction] public ComponentDataFromEntity<MarkForDelete> MarkForDelete;
        [NativeDisableParallelForRestriction] public ComponentDataFromEntity<IsCollidedComponent> IsCollidedComponent;
        [NativeDisableParallelForRestriction] public ComponentDataFromEntity<Velocity> VelocityComponents;
        [NativeDisableParallelForRestriction] public ComponentDataFromEntity<PhysicsVelocity> Velocities;
        [ReadOnly] public BufferTypeHandle<StatefulCollisionEvent> CollisionEventBufferType;
        [ReadOnly] public EntityTypeHandle EntityType;
        public EntityCommandBuffer.ParallelWriter Ecb;
        bool update;

        public void Execute(ArchetypeChunk chunk, int chunkIndex, int firstEntityIndex)
        {
            var collisionEventBuffers = chunk.GetBufferAccessor(CollisionEventBufferType);
            for (int i = 0; i < chunk.Count; i++)
            { //For each entity and corresponding DynamicBuffer<StatefulCollisionEvent> collisionEvents
                DynamicBuffer<StatefulCollisionEvent> collisionEvents = collisionEventBuffers[i];
                var entities = chunk.GetNativeArray(EntityType);
                Entity entity = entities[i];

                for (int j = 0; j < collisionEvents.Length; j++)
                {//For each collided entity in DynamicBuffer<StatefulCollisionEvent> collisionEvents of each entity
                    // Get collision event
                    var collision = collisionEvents[j];
                    // Get entity that collided with this entity
                    var otherEntity = collision.GetOtherEntity(entity);

                    if (collision.State == StatefulEventState.Enter)
                    { //The moment the collision occurs
                        var entityVelocity = VelocityComponents[entity];
                        var entityPhysicsVelocity = Velocities[entity];
                        var collidingEntityVelocity = VelocityComponents[otherEntity];
                        var collidingEntityPhysicsVelocity = Velocities[entity];

                        Entity dynamicEntity, staticEntity;

                        // Compare velocities to decide which entity to delete
                        if (math.length(entityVelocity.velocity) > math.length(collidingEntityVelocity.velocity)) {
                            dynamicEntity = entity;
                            staticEntity = otherEntity;
                            update = true;
                        } else if (math.length(entityVelocity.velocity) < math.length(collidingEntityVelocity.velocity)) {
                            dynamicEntity = otherEntity;
                            staticEntity = entity;
                            update = true;
                        } else {
                            // If velocities are equal, check the markForDelete component of colliding entity. If it is false, delete entity self
                            if (MarkForDelete[otherEntity].markForDelete && !MarkForDelete[entity].markForDelete) {
                                //Case: Colliding entity is already marked for delete; Do nothing to prevent over count
                                dynamicEntity = otherEntity;
                                staticEntity = entity;
                                update = false;
                            }
                            else if (!MarkForDelete[otherEntity].markForDelete && MarkForDelete[entity].markForDelete) {
                                //Case: Colliding entity is not marked for delete, but self is marked for delete; Do nothing to prevent over count
                                dynamicEntity = entity;
                                staticEntity = otherEntity;
                                update = false;
                            }
                            else {
                                //Case: Colliding entity is not marked for delete, and self is not marked for delete.
                                dynamicEntity = entity;
                                staticEntity = otherEntity;
                                update = false;
                                // We will update only when colliding entities' PhysicsVelocities and Velocities are both not equal to 0 since colliding entities cannot have a velocity of 0
                                if((!(math.length(entityPhysicsVelocity.Linear) == 0) && !(math.length(collidingEntityPhysicsVelocity.Linear) == 0))&&(!(math.length(entityVelocity.velocity) == 0) && !(math.length(collidingEntityVelocity.velocity) == 0))) {
                                    update = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // Is Collided
                        var dynamicEntityIsCollided = IsCollidedComponent[dynamicEntity];
                        if (update) {
                            if(!dynamicEntityIsCollided.isCollided) {
                                // Modify the size of the static entity by adding the size of the dynamic entity.
                                SizeComponent staticSize = Size[staticEntity];
                                SizeComponent dynamicSize = Size[dynamicEntity];

                                float currentArea = staticSize.width * staticSize.height;
                                float updatedArea = currentArea + dynamicSize.width * dynamicSize.height;
                                staticSize.width = math.sqrt(updatedArea/currentArea)*staticSize.width;
                                staticSize.height = math.sqrt(updatedArea/currentArea)*staticSize.height;
                                Size[staticEntity] = staticSize;

                                // Mark the dynamic entity for deletion.
                                MarkForDelete[dynamicEntity] = new MarkForDelete { markForDelete = true };

                                // Update isCollided value of entities that collided
                                IsCollidedComponent[dynamicEntity] = new IsCollidedComponent { isCollided = true };
                                IsCollidedComponent[staticEntity] = new IsCollidedComponent { isCollided = true };
                            }
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (collision.State == StatefulEventState.Stay)
                    { //collision occuring
                        var entityVelocity = VelocityComponents[entity];
                        var entityPhysicsVelocity = Velocities[entity];
                        var collidingEntityVelocity = VelocityComponents[otherEntity];
                        var collidingEntityPhysicsVelocity = Velocities[entity];

                        Entity dynamicEntity, staticEntity;

                        // Compare velocities to decide which entity to delete
                        if (math.length(entityVelocity.velocity) > math.length(collidingEntityVelocity.velocity)) {
                            dynamicEntity = entity;
                            staticEntity = otherEntity;
                            update = true;
                        } else if (math.length(entityVelocity.velocity) < math.length(collidingEntityVelocity.velocity)) {
                            dynamicEntity = otherEntity;
                            staticEntity = entity;
                            update = true;
                        } else {
                            // If velocities are equal, check the markForDelete component of colliding entity. If it is false, delete entity self
                            if (MarkForDelete[otherEntity].markForDelete && !MarkForDelete[entity].markForDelete) {
                                //Case: Colliding entity is already marked for delete; Do nothing to prevent over count
                                dynamicEntity = otherEntity;
                                staticEntity = entity;
                                update = false;
                            }
                            else if (!MarkForDelete[otherEntity].markForDelete && MarkForDelete[entity].markForDelete) {
                                //Case: Colliding entity is not marked for delete, but self is marked for delete; Do nothing to prevent over count
                                dynamicEntity = entity;
                                staticEntity = otherEntity;
                                update = false;
                            }
                            else {
                                //Case: Colliding entity is not marked for delete, and self is not marked for delete.
                                dynamicEntity = entity;
                                staticEntity = otherEntity;
                                update = false;
                                // We will update only when colliding entities' PhysicsVelocities and Velocities are both not equal to 0 since colliding entities cannot have a velocity of 0
                                if((!(math.length(entityPhysicsVelocity.Linear) == 0) && !(math.length(collidingEntityPhysicsVelocity.Linear) == 0))&&(!(math.length(entityVelocity.velocity) == 0) && !(math.length(collidingEntityVelocity.velocity) == 0))) {
                                    update = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // Is Collided
                        var dynamicEntityIsCollided = IsCollidedComponent[dynamicEntity];
                        if (update) {
                            if(!dynamicEntityIsCollided.isCollided) {
                                // Modify the size of the static entity by adding the size of the dynamic entity.
                                SizeComponent staticSize = Size[staticEntity];
                                SizeComponent dynamicSize = Size[dynamicEntity];

                                float currentArea = staticSize.width * staticSize.height;
                                float updatedArea = currentArea + dynamicSize.width * dynamicSize.height;
                                staticSize.width = math.sqrt(updatedArea/currentArea)*staticSize.width;
                                staticSize.height = math.sqrt(updatedArea/currentArea)*staticSize.height;
                                Size[staticEntity] = staticSize;

                                // Mark the dynamic entity for deletion.
                                MarkForDelete[dynamicEntity] = new MarkForDelete { markForDelete = true };

                                // Update isCollided value of entities that collided
                                IsCollidedComponent[dynamicEntity] = new IsCollidedComponent { isCollided = true };
                                IsCollidedComponent[staticEntity] = new IsCollidedComponent { isCollided = true };
                            }
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    { //The moment the collision exits
                        //Leave empty for now
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I move the game object fast enough, which should not even be that fast to a computer considering I'm sliding the x value with my freakin finger, I see the pass-through behavior:

[image]

It was really astonishing to find out that ECS sucks at one of the very few things it advertises to be good at - collision detection. Nevertheless, I want to have more faith in Unity. There must be some optimization step I am missing in my code. Could you please provide me insight what that may be?

Comment: The "pass-through" behaviour you describe is more commonly called tunnelling. It's not a limitation of ECS. It results from your choice to use discrete collision detection. If an object moves far enough in one physics step to land on the other side of an obstacle, there's never a moment when it hits it. Increasing the solver iterations doesn't change that, because this controls how many iterations to use in processing contact/joint constraints once two objects have been detected as interacting. You may instead want a shorter timestep, or to use **continuous collision detection**.

Comment: Is StatefulCollisionDetection essentially discrete collision detection? If I were to switch to ccd, what should I do?

Comment: I thought ECS supported CCD by default. I am googling and asking chat gpt for answers, but there seems to be very little documentation on CCD in DOTS ECS. Help appreciated!